# Are there benefits to returning a tapped hash over an immediate hash?

Tags: ruby

Some code under review used the pattern below a lot:

```
def some_method
  {}.tap do |data|
    data[:foo] = something
    data[:bar] = something_else
  end
end
```

I would have written this:

```
def some_method
  {
    foo: something,
    bar: something_else
  }
end
```

Are there technical reasons for using `tap` here, e.g., performance, memory, ...?

I can only think of two reasons:

- Minor contextual info because you can name the hash (*very* minor IMO)
- Doesn't require commas after elements (but requires *other* syntactic noise)

Comment: Use of conditionals? `data[:foo] = something if ...`

Comment: It stops people fighting over which hash syntax is better ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tap`, you could use conditionals (or more complex logic):

```
def some_method
  {}.tap do |data|
    data[:foo] = something if condition
    data[:bar] = something_else unless condition
  end
end
```

But even in this case, I'd probably avoid `tap` and write:

```
def some_method
  data = {}
  data[:foo] = something if condition
  data[:bar] = something_else unless condition
  data
end
```

Comment: I probably would too; I guess it's a stylistic thing. I just think the `tap` and nesting does more to obfuscate than just doing it the simplest way possible.

Comment: If the ruby bug regarding double splash is fixed, then we can do `{**({foo: something} if condition), ...}`.

Comment: @sawa indeed, another reason to have that fixed.